# google maps not showing unless id set to map_canvas

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get google maps api v3 to work, and well, it does! but **ONLY** when I set the div that displays the map to have an id of "map_canvas". Is that Id required? What if you want to display multiple maps on one page?

I am setting the id in BOTH my js and html markup

### It works flawlessly like this:

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
 function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
 }
</script>
```

HTML

```
 <div style="width:300px; height:300px;">
  <div style="width:100% height:100%" id="map_canvas"></div>
 </div>
```

### It loads the map according to firebug, but doesn't display anything when I do this:

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
 function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("anyotherid"), mapOptions);
 }
</script>
```

HTML

```
 <div style="width:300px; height:300px;">
  <div style="width:100% height:100%" id="anyotherid"></div>
 </div>
```

## Update

I uploaded an example page that reporduces my problem at:
[Example at athleticaustin.com/spots/test](http://athleticaustin.com/spots/test)

One peculiarity that I have noticed is that when I edit the id attribute with firebug from map_test to map_canvas on the div that displays the map, it suddenly appears even though the id is still defined as map_test in the JS in the head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a semicolon missing in

```
<div style="width:100% height:100%" id="anyotherid"></div>
```

it should be

```
<div style="width:100%; height:100%" id="anyotherid"></div>
```

(semicolon after width:100%;), but that semicolon is also missing in your map_canvas snippet, so it is probably not the issue, unless you copy/paste'd wrongly.

Comment: Ahhh thats all it was. I should have been validating. Thanks for the second pair of eyes!

Comment: And yes the semi colon was also missing when I used the map_canvas id successfully. Strange how all that works. It really threw me off when it worked fine for the first bit of testing and then when all I changed was the Id it decided to stop working. I didn't think a markup error was the problem since the markup had been working fine before so I didn't scrutinize it thoroughly.

Comment: It worked with map_canvas because in your <style> section you have  #map_canvas { height: 100% } ... (+1) for a well formulated question. :-)

Answer (score 2):

> Is that Id required?

No.

> What if you want to display multiple maps on one page?

You use multiple unique ids for the divs.

[Here is an example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search) from the documentation that uses "map"
If it isn't working for you, you are doing something wrong.  I don't see it in the snippets you have posted.  Do you have a live link or a jsfiddle that exhibits the issue?

Comment: I know it has to be something I am, or am not doing, but whats frustrating is the **only** difference between a working and non working map is the id. I was hoping someone else had come across this before. I guess I'll just keep working on it and report back if I figure out what kind of craziness is causing this. Thanks for the confirmation that map_canvas is not required, one more item I can eliminate from potential problems.

Comment: Added an example from the documentation that uses "map".  I have seen maps with multiple ids and multiple maps, just can't find one easily.

Comment: @Larry: Here's 16 maps on the same page, (although they are API V2): http://maps.forum.nu/gm_maps_in_sync2.html